# Errors occur while using mysql with liferay

Tags: mysql, liferay, tomcat7

I'm using Liferay v6.1 CE. I switched from Liferay's HSQL to MySQL v5.1.23 by following the instructions on [this page](http://thiranjith.com/2011/09/17/setting-up-liferay-with-mysql/) and other similar pages which have same instructions. But when I start the server, I get following errors in the browser, which I think are related to Tomcat. I have Apache Tomcat 7.0.23 btw.

My portal-ext.properties code:

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/liferaydb2?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=root
jdbc.default.password=theroot
```

Errors I get in the browser:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

exception

Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:80)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:230)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:184)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:184)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity: [com.liferay.portal.model.impl.CompanyImpl#10154]
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:911)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PageContextWrapper.handlePageException(PageContextWrapper.java:161)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:148)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:80)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:230)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:184)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:184)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
root cause

com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity: [com.liferay.portal.model.impl.CompanyImpl#10154]
com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.BasePersistenceImpl.processException(BasePersistenceImpl.java:193)
com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.CompanyPersistenceImpl.fetchByPrimaryKey(CompanyPersistenceImpl.java:531)
com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.CompanyPersistenceImpl.findByPrimaryKey(CompanyPersistenceImpl.java:475)
com.liferay.portal.service.impl.CompanyLocalServiceImpl.getCompanyById(CompanyLocalServiceImpl.java:602)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:112)
com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:71)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:108)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:59)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:108)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:59)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:108)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:211)
$Proxy15.getCompanyById(Unknown Source)
com.liferay.portal.service.CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyById(CompanyLocalServiceUtil.java:434)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getCompany(PortalImpl.java:1206)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getRelativeHomeURL(PortalImpl.java:3217)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getHomeURL(PortalImpl.java:1829)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getHomeURL(PortalUtil.java:516)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:114)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:80)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:230)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:184)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:184)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
root cause

com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity: [com.liferay.portal.model.impl.CompanyImpl#10154]
com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.ExceptionTranslator.translate(ExceptionTranslator.java:30)
com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:131)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ClassLoaderSession.get(ClassLoaderSession.java:237)
com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.CompanyPersistenceImpl.fetchByPrimaryKey(CompanyPersistenceImpl.java:525)
com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.CompanyPersistenceImpl.findByPrimaryKey(CompanyPersistenceImpl.java:475)

com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:112)
com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:71)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:108)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:59)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:108)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:59)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:108)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:211)
$Proxy15.getCompanyById(Unknown Source)
com.liferay.portal.service.CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyById(CompanyLocalServiceUtil.java:434)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getCompany(PortalImpl.java:1206)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getRelativeHomeURL(PortalImpl.java:3217)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getHomeURL(PortalImpl.java:1829)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getHomeURL(PortalUtil.java:516)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:114)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:80)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:230)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:184)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:184)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
root cause

com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.CompanyPersistenceImpl.fetchByPrimaryKey(CompanyPersistenceImpl.java:525)
com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.CompanyPersistenceImpl.findByPrimaryKey(CompanyPersistenceImpl.java:475)
com.liferay.portal.service.impl.CompanyLocalServiceImpl.getCompanyById(CompanyLocalServiceImpl.java:602)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:112)
com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:71)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:108)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:59)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:108)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:59)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:108)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:211)
$Proxy15.getCompanyById(Unknown Source)
com.liferay.portal.service.CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyById(CompanyLocalServiceUtil.java:434)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getCompany(PortalImpl.java:1206)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getRelativeHomeURL(PortalImpl.java:3217)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getHomeURL(PortalImpl.java:1829)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getHomeURL(PortalUtil.java:516)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:114)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' at line 1
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3250)
com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3179)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1420)
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2037)
org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3293)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:269)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1005)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:998)
com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:128)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ClassLoaderSession.get(ClassLoaderSession.java:237)
com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.CompanyPersistenceImpl.fetchByPrimaryKey(CompanyPersistenceImpl.java:525)
com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.CompanyPersistenceImpl.findByPrimaryKey(CompanyPersistenceImpl.java:475)
com.liferay.portal.service.impl.CompanyLocalServiceImpl.getCompanyById(CompanyLocalServiceImpl.java:602)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:112)
com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:71)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:108)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:59)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:108)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:59)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:108)
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:211)
$Proxy15.getCompanyById(Unknown Source)
com.liferay.portal.service.CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyById(CompanyLocalServiceUtil.java:434)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getCompany(PortalImpl.java:1206)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getRelativeHomeURL(PortalImpl.java:3217)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getHomeURL(PortalImpl.java:1829)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getHomeURL(PortalUtil.java:516)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:114)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:80)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:230)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:184)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:184)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the issue by replacing 'mysql.jar' in tomcat's lib/ext directory with the latest mysql-connnector-j jar, as per guidance by David H Nebinger on [liferay's forum page](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/23650072).

Comment: key is to use the mysql connector that matches your mysql installation. They seem to have changed something lately